# How do I match one table data to another then display the matched data? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc and I'm struggling to figure out the correct way to do the following:
My question involves 3 tables from my database

- City
- Client
- Conciege (service provider)

I need to create a welcome page when my user signs up that displays two things,

1. the concierge name
2. the concierge photo

To do this I need to check the database when the user signs up what city they inputted and match that city with my concierge's city then display 1 & 2.

This is what I have so far:

Controller:

```
        public async Task<List<ServiceProviders_vs_LocationsModel>> GetConciege()
    {
        try
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("GetConciege").Result;

            var stringcontent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                List<ServiceProviders_vs_LocationsModel> Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServiceProviders_vs_LocationsModel>>(stringcontent);

                return Result;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class ServiceProviders_vs_LocationsModel
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public int ServiceProviderID { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
            <Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyApp.Images.Sub_logo_icon.png}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
            <Label
                FontFamily="AnimalCrossing"
                FontSize="30"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Welcome To Hey Maggie"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>

        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollView.VerticalOptions>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="LayoutOptions"
                         Default="CenterAndExpand"
                         Phone="FillAndExpand" />
            </ScrollView.VerticalOptions>


            <StackLayout
                Spacing="0"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                WidthRequest="{OnPlatform Default='-1'}" Margin="30,0,30,0">



                <Grid RowSpacing="10" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyApp.Images.Sub_logo_icon.png}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Margin="60,0,50,0" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <!--conciege photo loaded here-->

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" >Your Friendly Conciege Will Be</Label> 
                    </StackLayout>
                    <!--conciege name loaded here-->


                    <Button Style="{DynamicResource PrimaryButton}" Grid.Row="7" Text="Sign Up" HeightRequest="50" Clicked="GetStarted_Clicked" />


                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>


</ContentPage.Content>
```

View.cs:

```
        public WelcomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GetStarted_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new Views.Dashboard();//navigates to dashboard
    }
}
```

I can read and understand code but find it hard to write what I want the program to do/ find it hard to get the correct results on google.
Please help a junior developer out XP

Comment: This is a little confusing. You're description is ASP.NET and the tag is asp.net-mvc. However, some of your code looks like WPF. Look at the View - that's XAML.

Comment: Yes the view is xaml

Comment: You need to clearly define what the problem you're having is, so that we may present our thoughts on it and possibly the solutions to overcome that problem. I can't see a clear problem description, like exceptions, value not showing up in certain parts of the page etc. If you want people to figure this code out for you and teach it to you,  you may have come to the wrong place. You may need to find a good tutorial website for asp mvc with xaml view components.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using linq inside of the c# code.